# Google Map with Default direction

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my site I've already implemented Google Map Direction API Version-3. With this I can show the direction between places by choosing from the selectbox.

Now I want to implement another map which will load initially with the directions I have given. Also with point to point direction. I want to print the map with the map and the directions. But I cannot load the map with directions when the page loads. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could show some code so we can tell you what is wrong...

Here are the steps that you should take in order to show the directions when the page loads:

- show the map
- find the coordinates for the locations (if you haven't got them
  already, use the geocoding service
  from google maps)
- create a request to send to the directions service from google
- send the request and get the result from it
- show the result on the map

Don't forget that the geocoding and directions services are asynchronous and you will have to write the code for what happens after the results are received in a callback function.